# Why does kotlin not allows to define property or annotate in the secondary constructor?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, dagger, kotlin-android-extensions

I am using dagger dependency injection in my application,I use `Qualifiers` to inject my class with secondary `constructor` with `Qualifier`, But kotlin shows me compile time error says `This annotation is not applicable to target value parameter`
***Example***

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class Car
```

```
open class BaseClass {

}

class TestingClass : BaseClass {

    @Inject
    constructor(@Car vehicle : Vehicle) : super() {

    }
}
```

In the above class am not able to inject the class `Vehicle` with `@Car` qualifier, Can anyone help me why this is not possible in secondary constructor of kotlin ?

Comment: how is `@Car` annotation defined?

Comment: @sidgate edited.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, my build works fine with your code. Did you try adding `@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)` to your annotation?